# How to convert 1k to 1000 and 1m to 1000000 in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have text data containing numbers with abbreviations for thousands (k) and millions (m).  I want to convert these to numeric values. For example `1.2k` to `1200` and `1.8m` to `1800000`. How can I do that?

Comment: As an aside, a million is typically represented with a capital 'M'. In SI, small 'm' stands for "milli".

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev it's neither here nor there, but you *should* be able to use `upper()` or `lower()` to retain case-sensitivity on the data but typographically output your preferred aesthetic choice?

Answer (score 22):

You can use search to return the relative position in a string of the suffix.  Then raise ten to that number time 3.

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*10^(SEARCH(RIGHT(A1),"kmbt")*3)
```

[image]

To handle ones with out the suffix:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*10^(SEARCH(RIGHT(A1),"kmbt")*3),A1)
```

Comment: Note that this will mishandle a number without a suffix.

Comment: Just because its fun, this works with prefixes kMGT `=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)&"e"&CHOOSE(INT((CODE(UPPER(RIGHT(A1)))-65)/4),9,3,6,12),A1)`. The ascii code itself becomes an input to a formula, which maps to an index in CHOOSE to assign the correct order of magnitude.

Answer (score 10):

*You can use this Formula to convert abbreviated data into Numbers:*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `C80` & fill it down.

  `=IFNA(LEFT(A80,LEN(A80)-1)*CHOOSE(MATCH(RIGHT(A80,1), {"K","M","B"},0),1000,1000000,1000000000),A80)`

**N.B.**

- `MATCH(RIGHT(A80,1),{"K","M","B"},0)`, 
  returns `1` for `K`, `2` for `M` & `3` for `B`.
- `CHOOSE` returns `1,000`, `1,000,000` or `1,000,000,000` which is multiplied by `LEFT(A80,LEN(A80)-1)`.
- `LEFT` removes the `K` or `M`.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: This formula has the benefit of handling a number without a letter.

Answer (score 2):

If the suffixes are real SI prefixes then you can use Excel's [`CONVERT()` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-function-d785bef1-808e-4aac-bdcd-666c810f9af2) to get the numeric values

```
=CONVERT(VALUE(LEFT(A2, LEN(A2) - 1)), RIGHT(A2, 1) & "m", "m")
         ▲                          ▲  ▲          ▲
         └─────────────┬────────────┘  └─────┬────┘
                     value         value suffix/SI prefix
```

The trick here is to convert km, Mm... to m, but of course instead of meter you can use any SI basic units. The thousand suffix must be k in lowercase for kilo, and the million suffix must be uppercase M for Mega

[image: Excel convert example]