# Trying to convert 1k to 1000

Tags: microsoft-excel, macbook

I have  data containing numbers with abbreviations for thousands (k) and I want to convert them to from k to 1000

I have been trying these 2 functions

```
=IFNA(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*CHOOSE(MATCH(RIGHT(A1,1),{"K","M"},0),1000,1000000),A1)

=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*10^(SEARCH(RIGHT(A1),"kmbt")*3)
```

with both of them, the same error shows:

> Not trying to type a formula?
>
> When the first character is an equal ("=") or minus ("-") sign, Excel thinks it's a formula:
>
> • you type:   =1+1, cell shows:   2
>
> To get around this, type an apostrophe ( ' ) first: 
> • you type:   '=1+1, cell shows:   =1+1"

Is there anyway to solve this ?

Thanks:)

Comment: The second one works fine for me on Excel 2019 for Windows, though it should probably say `"kMGT"` instead of `"kmbt"` for gigabytes...

Comment: For me both formulas work if `A1` has values like 1k or 2m. What values do you originally have?

Comment: Just try pasting these formulas again. I think you had some problem pasting them originally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert 1k to 1000 and 1m to 1000000 in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1459247/how-to-convert-1k-to-1000-and-1m-to-1000000-in-excel)

Comment: 2nd one works for me on Excel 2010.   Appears to be case agnostic - I can type 1k or 1K, it still comes up with 1000.

Comment: Perhaps your Windows regional settings specifies the semicolon instead of the comma to separate the formula arguments.

Comment: Both works for me on Excel 2016. IFNA requires Excel 2013 and newer - this one works for both normal numbers and once with k / m / etc multipliers. Second one doesn't work for normal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
=SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"K","e3")+0
```

Or for K and M:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),"K","e3"),"M","e6")+0
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this. If it's more clear, OP, you can also wrap the substitution inside `VALUE()` to get a number result instead of text. (This is what the `+0` at the end does now.)

Comment: “Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler” — [tentatively attributed to Albert Einstein](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/). This will fail for input that contains a decimal point; e.g., ```7.5k```.

Comment: Fine. I'll go boss level 99. :) Replaced "000" with "e3" in the formula, so that decimals points are handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This converts any metric prefix, e.g. 5p or 10Z:

```
=IFERROR(CONVERT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),RIGHT(A1)&"L","L"),A1)
```

Allowed prefixes from 10^24 down to 10^-24 include Y,Z,E,P,T,G,M,k,h,e,d,c,m,u,n,p,f,a,z,y. Note case sensitivity.